# SFTP JCA Connector?

Tags: java, spring, sftp, jboss6.x, jca

I'm building a Spring 3.0 app that is running on JBoss 6.x.  I have a need for my application to access files (get and put) via sftp.  Having never done this before, I did some research and found that Spring-Integration has support for sftp.  However, the architect on this project is insisting that the connection must come from the container and not from the app.

Consequently, I find myself searching for an SFTP JCA, but cannot find anything of value.  I did run across [txconnect.sourceforge.net](http://txconnect.sourceforge.net) but the library seems as though there is no active development and does not support ssh keys (only username/pwd).

Is there anything out there that I can use?  Searching on Google has turned up nothing.  Can Spring be configured as a JCA for JBoss?  Do I need something else?

Thanks!
Eric

Comment: This sounds like an over-complicated solution.  JCA is a complex beast. Can't you just use an SFTP library directly, never mind Spring Integration or JCA?

Comment: I'm sorry - what do you mean by using an sftp library directly?  The problem with having the app itself open sockets to transfer files is that is runs against J2EE best practices, in which it is the container that initiates all socket io.  Plugging an sftp lib directly in the app circumvents that approach and could potentially cause problems in clustered environments.

Comment: In my experience, "J2EE best practices" is an oxymoron. Go with what works, is my advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One general thing: In the long run it's wise to stick to your specs unless you really know what hurting it can mean for your project.

So, if you are sure that you want to / must use JCA, here's something:

A quick search gave me two connectors:

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jca-for-ssh/
2. http://jca-for-ssh.sourceforge.net

They don't appear to be that mature, although I didn't use them myself.

What do you need your connector for? If it's just simple things, you can also write one yourself.
For example: do you need transaction support? Do you need to support both inbound and outbound connections?

In case you have more questions, let me know :-)

Comment: I just found another link: [link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikasaneip/index.php?title=Explanation_of_the_Code_Base). There is no sourcecode there yet, but it looks promising, so you should probably send those guys a mail asking for their SFTP RA.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a stretch, but https://www.advantco.com/product/adapter/sftp provides what they claim is a *native JCA Adapter which plugs into the existing J2EE Adapter Framework*, but appears to be targeted at the SAP NetWeaver framework, so not sure what kind of luck you will have with JBoss integration.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried contacting them, but their adapter is SAP specific and their other product is standalone app; not a jca.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your requirements is, that you need to open ssh connections from your app running in JBOSS to a remote system in order to download and upload files from/to there.

In my opinion you don't need a JCA adapter. I'm not an expert on Spring but since you're talking about JBOSS I can tell you that is forbidden for any EE6 application  to open server sockets(listen), but allowed to open client ones.

If you wanted to emulate an SSH server functionality in your app, then you would need to implement a JCA adapter but in your case not.